# How to create shapes on drawable layout android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml, drawable

I need to create a layout that will be with rounded corners, but in which there will be various shapes.

I have a sample (in the screenshot below). I created a layout with rounded corners and the right color, but I don’t know if I can create a few more shapes on it (these shapes are dark in the screenshot) and if I can place them where I want?

[image]

My code for background shape:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="@color/purple_light" />
    <corners android:radius="16dp" />

</shape>
```

Answer (score 2):

You have 2 choices:

1- Export the complete shape as a vector (SVG) and import it into Android Studio.
Then you can use this shape wherever you want.
(Whole purple background with triangle shaped inside of it)

2- Trying to draw that shape on Android Studio.
You have to do something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/purple_200" />
            <corners android:radius="1dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_baseline_square_24"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_baseline_triangle"/>
</layer-list>
```

But you need to completely design shapes with the drawable.

I tried quickly just for showing you the result:

[Sample output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LRQJJ.png)

Answer (score 1):

You can use android layer list drawable. You can refer the docs [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource#LayerList).